# What's the name of this file icon theme for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me the name of this file icon theme?

The Screenshot is from [Tailwind Breeze Theme for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=praveenpuglia.tailwind-breeze)

[image]

Comment: the best place to ask is on there Repo, ask to add it in the picture caption, like in the VSCode release notes it mentions the Theme name

Comment: I already did that two weeks ago and got no answer so i posted it here and I've found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons)-- this is the set I am using and the few icons I made matched your picture.

Comment: I tried and it's the right one, thanks